# Android : paint parameter in Canvas.drawBitmap

Tags: android, android-canvas

I use below code to get the height and width of the mobile screen and then make a random number in that range and make an image in a random place of the screen :

```
DisplayMetrics displaymetrics = new DisplayMetrics();
    getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(displaymetrics);
    int height = displaymetrics.heightPixels;
    int width = displaymetrics.widthPixels;

    int x = (int) (Math.random() * height);
    int y = (int) (Math.random() * width);

    Canvas.drawBitmap(R.drawable.sizem, x, y, paint);
```

But I dont no how can I fill the paint parameter in the last line :

```
Canvas.drawBitmap(R.drawable.sizem, x, y, paint);
```

Comment: what do you want to do with Paint parameter?

Comment: @pskink I just want  make an image in a random place of the screen

Comment: so just pass null value

Comment: just create a new paint instance. new Paint().

Answer (score 0):

Check [drawBitmap](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Canvas.html#drawBitmap%28android.graphics.Bitmap,%20float,%20float,%20android.graphics.Paint%29)

> paint     The paint used to draw the bitmap (may be null)

Try
Canvas.drawBitmap(R.drawable.sizem, x, y, null);